# UIScrollView zooming and panning

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

I've got a `UIViewController` with a `UIView`.

I put inside an `UIScrollView` with another `UIView` inside, all in my storyboard with `AutoLayout`.

After `ViewDidLoad` method I create an array of `UIButton` to represent them as a matrix `N`x`M`.

The matrix can go out of bounds but the scrollview is here for a reason.

When I pan some `UIButton`s don't capture any touch event and if I zoom the `UIScrollView` doesn't zoom very well, is not centered and it brokes the panning.

Anybody knows why?

Comment: attach a screenshot how it breaks in panning?

Comment: the panning breaks because I can't go anywhere without zooming out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue implementing the `UIScrollViewDelegate` like this:

```
func scrollViewDidEndZooming(scrollView: UIScrollView, withView view: UIView!, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
    let w = max(scrollView.frame.size.width, totalWidth)
    let h = max(scrollView.frame.size.height, totalHeight)
    view.frame.size = CGSize(width: w * scale, height: h * scale)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: w * scale, height: h * scale)
}
```

So it recalculate size correctly and zooming and panning worked nice

Comment: What is totalHeight, totalWidth?